# JavaScript elment.nextSibling is not working

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following code at https://jsfiddle.net/g6fqrxLz/, and rating.nextSibling seems is having problem getting the next sibling. I not sure what's the cause for this error

```
 <div class="star-rating">
   <div class="off">&#9733</div>
   <div class="off">&#9733</div>
   <div class="off">&#9733</div>
   <div class="off">&#9733</div>
   <div class="off">&#9733</div>
</div>
<input type="input" name="rating" class="rating-input" />

var rating = document.getElementsByClassName('star-rating')[0];
var ratingInput = rating.nextSibling;
alert(ratingInput.className);
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a node list, not a single element.

Comment: The next sibling after the <div> is a TextNode containing the line break. It doesn't have a `className`, therefore you're getting `undefined`. One way to fix this is to put the `<input>` immediately after the `</div>`, not in the next line.

Comment: or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling   and you got desired element: https://jsfiddle.net/g6fqrxLz/1/

Comment: @Pointy ... that's why the code uses `[0]` to get the first such item from the list - and `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, which is not quite the same as a NodeList :p

Comment: how did I miss that; I must need sleep or something